# Is there any way to add electret microphone on raspberry-pi zero?If yes then how?

Tags: rpi.gpio, pi-zero

Is there any way to add an electret microphone on pi-zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no analog Audio-In pin on any of the RPi boards, so there is no way to simply connect a microphone. Your best bet is to use a USB sound card which as a built-in microphone or microphone input.

Comment: Ok Can we add a bluetooth 4.0 on pi zero using HATs?

Comment: Yes, again via USB.

Comment: Is there any way without USB to add on-board devices(like microphone , and bluetooth) on pi-zero.

Comment: Not without writing custom kernel drivers. Could you explain why using USB is an issue?

Comment: I know there is no issue regarding USB except the drivers, but without using USB, adding some devices on-board isn't would be the cool thing : )

Comment: My point is, you cannot just add a microphone (or a bluetooth antenna) on the board and get it working. You'll need to add a complete new device anyway (sound card or radio module), and USB devices are the easiest to obtain and set up.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47459/discussion-between-ajay-and-dmitry-grigoryev).